# Eclipse - Configure build path libraries is greayed out

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm very new to java and Eclipse.

I have downloaded a third party project and have made a change to one of the libraries and would like to replace it with mine.

When I try to configure build path libraries, all the libraries are greyed out.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Delete everything from bulid path except link to JDK then link everything again from your computer. It will work

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?